# Sending "commands" into React components?

Tags: reactjs

Just to provide some context and hopefully make my question clearer, I'll present a scenario that works, and will make sense.

Let's say we have an `AudioTrack` component, which renders play, stop, and seek controls. When the user seeks, that info is passed back to us:

```
<AudioTrack playingId={this.state.playingId} onSeek={this.handleSeek} />
```

(`playingId` indicates the ID of the currently playing track)

But what if we move the seek control outside the audio tracks, and so the seek control exists in the parent `<TrackList>` and will control whichever track is currently playing. Now I need to "send a command" with data into the appropriate track, e.g.:

```
<AudioTrack playingId={this.state.playingId} seekTo={this.state.newPos} onSeek={this.seekComplete} />
```

This feels hacky to me, but basically when the user lets go of the seek bar, it would set the `newPos` state in `TrackList`, which triggers `AudioTrack`'s `componentWillReceiveProps`. It seeks to the new position, then could report back via `onSeek` which would do `this.setState({ newPos: null })` in `TrackList`.

Am I thinking about this correctly, or is there a better way? In an ideal world, I could just directly call a method of the `AudioTrack`.

Answer (score -5):

You must use redux or flux for these kind of things. When working with react, you should store EVERY component in a redux/flux store. In fact you should not use constructor(props) ever, and store everything in the store. This will fix your 'hacky' issue. You can make the direct call to your redux store which is exactly what you are looking for.

I cannot iterate more on the importance of redux and react. You must use them together.

https://github.com/reactjs/redux

Comment: Redux is absolutely not required, and in many cases it winds up being overused actually. I wouldn't normally comment, but I didn't want absolute beginners reading "you must use them together" and think that's true.

Comment: This just isn't true. Even if you *do* use Redux/etc., it's certainly not true that you *must* keep all state in the Redux store. For example, UI state may not belong in Redux (e.g., http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state-only-redux-state) and the canonical https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367#.hud5vjfhj Note that I use Redux and enjoy it quite a bit, but in particular I keep UI state in the necessary components.